# Grothendieck group of coconnective dg-algebra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-k-theory, operads, differential-graded-algebras

Is there an example of an $E_{2}$-coconnective differential graded algebra $A$ (with unit) such that $K_{0}(A)=0$ ?